# Map.get() returning undefined

Tags: typescript

I want to populate my map, memo, with viewID for the key and an array for the value. I want to concatenate onto the array if i encounter the same viewID in my loop, however typescript is telling me preconcat is possibly undefined. I thought using the has() method would avoid this but, still the same issue. Any help?

```
let memo:Map<string,{}[]> = new Map<string,{}[]> ();
    let total_row_count:number = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < assetLoadQuery.length; i++) {
        const arrayOfPerformanceResourceTiming = JSON.parse(assetLoadQuery[i].performanceResourceTimingJSON);
        const viewID:string = assetLoadQuery[i].viewID;
        if(memo.has(viewID)) {
            const preconcat = memo.get(viewID);
            const concat = preconcat.concat(arrayOfPerformanceResourceTiming);
            memo.set(viewID, concat);
        } else {
            memo.set(viewID, arrayOfPerformanceResourceTiming);
        }  
        total_row_count++;
    }

   src/v1/metrics/asset-load.ts:50:28 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

50             const concat = preconcat.concat(arrayOfPerformanceResourceTiming);
                              ~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the non-null assertion operator.

read the docs:

> A new ! post-fix expression operator may be used to assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined in contexts where the type checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation x! produces a value of the type of x with null and undefined excluded. Similar to type assertions of the forms x and x as T, the ! non-null assertion operator is simply removed in the emitted JavaScript code.

here is an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAtiUPYC4CyBDADgHgM5gE4EsA7AcwBoBtAXQD4IBeCQkAdwlUxwJIpogAoAlAG4AUBHERQkMHDApgAfVxxmCgMZwAroTAJCmqACMQuehAAMokRsI4IKLFnAAZOCgAmARU0mAnmfIAbzQTADM4XCgUQjUQACUQLC1cWIAVfCgiYgApAGUAeQA5BAgAclLSCAA3fBYASQAREvKAX0oREXDcPikIfDNLPogMe0cXNy8fXF8AOlASMAALIT6AalWBCECxCRs7FFxcFF980IAFMIiomPjE5LSMrLM8opm0A6c%20BycwVw9vPzkfCUN6XSLRWIJJKaFIgdKZEgvQrCHbiPaQGr1JqcJ4Mb7jf5TXxAkGY5iNUQSPqhPgweAzRYOPhkxoCTbbKlU9EQNC4EA2NQoSAMOlwGbEcDM2rkhoozm7OC2SACoVmXn8xWCsAAQhmKrAX0Ox1OF1wXWukLuMIeCOIcvl0FgYp%20UqxlX1owgVHt4haEBAwCcW1RnNFMxdLIalQORxO5zBFtu0Nh8KyPogfogIZkckUylUGm0YHWohaIiAA)

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign what kind of array it is, otherwise you are just typing it as an empty array/tuple `[]`, so an array with 0 elements:

```
const memo = new Map<string,any[]>()
```

Replace `any` with the type that it actually contains.